# How can I read a windows backup from ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, backup

I have a backup of a windows system (I think it is win7, but it might be vista).  That I took using the windows system tools.  I need to be able to access these files from an ubuntu environment.

The backup is on an external USB hard drive.  I can see the files, basically a bunch of zip files.   I suppose I could manually open each one, but that strikes me as rather a tedious business.

More specific, but probably not relevant:

This is a netbook that I was attempting to dual boot with windows and ubuntu. I did take a careful backup before starting, which is a good thing since I accidentally deleted the windows partions.  Sigh.  Really, more than anything else I need the user data,  Documents and downloads directory, and especially the firefox profile info.

Comment: This question should belong on SuperUser.

Comment: Isn't there a restore option on the Win7/ Vista DVD?

Comment: I don't have a win7 DVD.  this was a preinstalled netbook.  recovery options all on disk

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure exactly how you could open these in ubuntu, but I have used a boot disk called Hirens Boot CD before now which contains lots of backup and recovery tools.

It may help you recover some of your data : 
http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [page about it](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/174270-backup-manually-extract-files-vista-windows-7-a.html), although it involves running EXEs, merging separate files into one EXE and the like, so I doubt you'll be doing it natively on Ubuntu. I would suggest setting up a Windows 7 guest (in 30-day trial mode or whatever it is you get) under VirtualBox and using that for the extraction.

Comment: That page is really for extracting a windows backup in windows.  Not what I am looking for at all.  I have lost my last windows environment at home.  I would prefer not to go through the effort of installing one, but that may be what I need to do.